# Speed performance between bitwise and simple logic

Tags: performance, time, execution

I was trying to find out the speed difference between bitwise operator XOR and simple arithmetic logic for a variable swap. I wrote a simple programme:-

```
 for(long i=0; i<1500000; i++){
    a=a+b;
    b=a-b;
    a=a-b;
}
```

whereas for XOR,It is

```
for(long i=0; i<1500000; i++){
    a=a^b;
    b=a^b;
    a=a^b;
}
```

I thought that the bitwise operator would be faster as it just uses two gates but it turns out that the arithmetic logic one is actually a little bit more fast and if you take a seprate variable for the swap, it's time is almost half of the other two. Can someone explain how this is so.

Comment: [XOR swap won't be faster than simple assignments in modern architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm#Reasons_for_use_in_practice)

Comment: It most certainly depends on the programming language you are using.

Comment: Modern processors are much more complex than just a few logic gates. Also, measuring performance reliably is much more complex than writing a loop and timing it.  You should read a bit on the subject of microbenchmarks and why they are much harder to get right than you could expect.

Answer (score 0):

I think that i finally have the answer to my own question. In most of the computers, assignment's are done by nand and nor gates because they are the ones that are the most easy to fabricate. XOR gates require minimum of three steps of combination of these gates to be implemented, i.e 3 gate delays. In arithmetic operations like addition, you can implement the carry look-ahead adder in 3 gate delays too. Hence, there is no timing difference.